# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise - Offline installer cross-platform?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I need to travel next month to an area of the world with very poor internet service, this was never an issue before as I just took the vs iso images along with me on a sd card and re-installed at the other end.

But, now I'm using VS2017 the only option appears to be the 'offline installer' so I'm wondering if I create an offline install of my current vs2017/win7 setup, will I then be able to install this from a sd card onto a win10 machine at the other end?

Comment: try [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/installing-visual-studio-2017-made-easy/)

Comment: That's not what "cross platform" means. And yes, the VS 2017 offline installer downloads all of the installer package files to a directory you can then install from - it's huge: tens of gigabytes. Be warned.

Comment: @Dai I wasn't sure, but have a look at the wikis for "Cross-platform" & "Computing platform" the definitions are broad and seem to suggest win7 and win10 are separate platforms.

Comment: ok, so you want to develop programs for Desktop? This is the same for Win7/10. Cross platform in VS2017 means Xamarin which allows to create iOS, Android and Windows Store apps with same c# codebase.

Comment: Downloading the whole thing was nearly 40GB which is bigger than any of my SD cards.  The C++ part is only about 2GB, so lets see if it unpacks without issue at the other end on a different version of windows.